# Nautilus becomes unresponsive, dmesg reports: "Valid eCryptfs headers not found..."

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, ecryptfs

The other day I was installing some stuff via software center, when suddenly nautilus becomes unresponsive to the point where it just hangs until I restart.

Now whenever I boot, Nautilus will work fine for 10 seconds then become unresponsive. I checked dmesg and it's filled with this:

```
[  385.392295] Valid eCryptfs headers not found in file header region or xattr region
[  385.392304] Either the lower file is not in a valid eCryptfs format, or the key could not be retrieved. Plaintext passthrough mode is not enabled; returning -EIO
```

I found a few bug reports, with no solution. I'm not even sure if that's causing it but seems to be the issue. Wouldn't be so bad if Ubuntu One worked, but it refuses to sync now.

Any ideas?

- I setup encryption on this drive during install.
- I should mention if I do gksudo nautilus . in the command line it works fine

Comment: Did you use encryption on your drive when you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, let me amend the post.

Comment: Do you use Wifi? What kind of Wifi card is in your computer? Many reports indicate that this problem is somehow connected to Wifi setup.

Comment: Perhaps this bug is related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/509180

Comment: This is likely an ecryptfs issue, unrelated to nautilus. However, since nautilus works with files, issues with the filesystem can cause nautilus to hang. The error message says the encrypted files are corrupted, which could be caused by a bug in ecryptfs, a hardware error (badblocks) or someone tried to manipulate the encrypted files (as root).

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you created a root-owned file/dir that's not readable by you. You can find the file(s)/dir(s) with the "find" command.

```
sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER -ls
```

The "sudo" is in there so that find can traverse root-owned directories. You can (probably)  fix them with find, as well:

```
MYgroup=$( id -g )
sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER -exec chown $USER:$MYgroup {} \;
```

Note: I should have a single backslash (for shell quoting) before each exclamation or semicolon.